# javafx pass fx:id to controller or parameter in fxml onAction method

Tags: binding, controller, javafx

Is there any way to pass parameters to the onAction methods in the fxml files? Alternatively, can I somehow get the fx:id of the component that called the onAction method?

I have several Buttons that should do the same thing, say 5 buttons with ids button1 - button5  that, when pressed, should print the corresponding number 1-5. I don't want to have 5 onAction methods that are identical up to this variable.

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call just one handler, the actionEvent.source is the object that originated the event.

Try this:

```
myButton1.setOnAction(new MyButtonHandler());
myButton2.setOnAction(new MyButtonHandler());

private class MyButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource().equals(myButton1)) {
          //do something
        } else if (evt.getSource().equals(myButton2)) {
          //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
myButton1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new MyButtonHandler());
myButton2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.CLICKED, new MyButtonHandler());

private class MyButtonHandler implements EventHandler<Event>{
    @Override
    public void handle(Event evt) {
        if (evt.getSource().equals(myButton1)) {
          //do something
        } else if (evt.getSource().equals(myButton2)) {
          //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DmitryNelepov I was edit the answer with some examples, hope this help you.