# Better way for Getting id of the clicked Object in JavaFX controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I`m looking for a better way for getting the id of the clicked object inside the event handler for this object.

I already found this:

[javafx pass fx:id to controller or parameter in fxml onAction method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085076/javafx-pass-fxid-to-controller-or-parameter-in-fxml-onaction-method)

But that did not work for me.

Now I'm using the getId() function of the node class like this:

```
Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
String id = btn.getId();
```

But i want to use this method not only for buttons.

Comment: Do you want to get the `id` or the `fx:id` for Buttons, Labels and other controls, when you click on them ?

Comment: I want to get the fx:id

Comment: Why do you want the fx:id in the control ? `fx:id` is used in the fxml to bind with controls in the controller. There is no point in getting the `fx:id`. May I know the reason why you are trying to fetch the fx:id ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since fx:id is used to bind controls between FXML and Controller, this answer is taking into consideration that OP wants the `id` of the controls when clicked.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IdForControlsOnClick extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        VBox vBox = new VBox(20);
        borderPane.setCenter(vBox);

        Button button = new Button("Hi");
        button.setId("Button");
        Label label = new Label("Label");
        label.setId("Label");
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setId("CheckBox");

        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new MyEventHandler());
        label.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new MyEventHandler());
        checkBox.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new MyEventHandler());

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(button, label, checkBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<Event>{
        @Override
        public void handle(Event evt) {
           System.out.println(((Control)evt.getSource()).getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works only if the clicked object extends Control. Both Button and Label do, but other items like MenuItem doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

I use this for getting the id of ImageView objects that all share the same event code. Here is a simple example using MouseEvent:

```
  @FXML
  private void selectImage(MouseEvent event)
    {
    String source1 = event.getSource().toString(); //yields complete string
    String source2 = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode().getId(); //returns JUST the id of the object that was clicked
    System.out.println("Full String: " + source1);
    System.out.println("Just the id: " + source2);
    System.out.println(" " + source2);
    }
```

Here is the output in my situation, where I used SceneBuilder to assign the selectImage method to the 'On Mouse Pressed' event, then running the code and randomly clicking on three different ImageView objects:

`Full String: ImageView[id=iv1, styleClass=image-view]
Just the id: iv1

Full String: ImageView[id=iv4, styleClass=image-view]
Just the id: iv4

Full String: ImageView[id=iv6, styleClass=image-view]
Just the id: iv6`

I hope this helps someone.  :-)