# Track clicked label - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, vbox

I have 5 labels in a vBox. I want to create a method for tracking which label I clicked. Right now, I am using 5 methods, one for each label. Do I need to use a listener or something else?
[Here is a fragment of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaEhe.png).

My fxml code:

```
<VBox layoutX="13.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="117.0" prefWidth="68.0" spacing="8.0">
     <children>
        <Label fx:id="firstLabelTime" onMouseClicked="#setFirstLabelTime" text="Input time" />
        <Label fx:id="secondLabelTime" onMouseClicked="#setSecondLabelTime" text="Label" />
        <Label fx:id="thirdLabelTime" onMouseClicked="#setThirdLabelTime" text="Label" />
        <Label fx:id="fourthLabelTime" onMouseClicked="#setFourthLabelTime" text="Label" />
        <Label fx:id="fifthLabelTime" onMouseClicked="#setFifthLabelTime" text="Label" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

My java methods:

```
private Label tempLabelTime;
@FXML
private void setFirstLabelTime() {
        tempLabelTime = firstLabelTime;
        openTimePicker();

}

@FXML
private void setSecondLabelTime() {
    tempLabelTime = secondLabelTime;
    openTimePicker();
}

@FXML
private void setThirdLabelTime() {
    tempLabelTime = thirdLabelTime;
    openTimePicker();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the MouseEvent into a common event handler.  Like this:

```
@FXML
private void labelClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Label label = (Label) e.getSource();  // this is the label that initiated the event
    openTimePicker(label);                // openTimePicker knows what to do with each label clicked
}
```

You could also pass `label.getId()` or `label.getText()`.

Additionally, see [this Stack Overflow discussion on JavaFx mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302636/better-way-for-getting-id-of-the-clicked-object-in-javafx-controller).

Finally, I'd recommend against using the class-level field as a temporary variable.   You can delegate the label-specific logic to the `openTimePicker` method instead so that the controller can remain stateless.  This reduces the opportunity for bugs later on!    Ideally, you want to implement your controller as a stateless adapter between the user and your service classes.